# How to change color of Font in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to change color of the font using the available options like `.setFontColor` and options with in parentheses but color is not being changed (However Bold option is working).

```
function temp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
templateSheet.getRange("G24").getValue().bold(COLOR="BLUE")
}
```

Request you to please help me in this regard.

Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `setFontColor()` after `getValue()`, you have to call it for a range. Bold is working because you are calling it from the text in the cell (after calling `getValue()`), so try this instead:

```
function temp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  templateSheet.getRange("G24").setFontColor("Blue");
}
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontcolorcolor) is `setFontColor()`'s documentation for further reference.